# JQuery Putting a header tag inside of a div tag

Tags: jquery, html

Attempted to attach a simple header into a div element. Confused as to why
it is not working. The h1 tag indicates a value of loading.

```
   <div data-role="page" id="addviewtask">
    <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
        <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px">
            <h2 class="header-font"> Page </h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">View Tasks</a><br>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Add Task</a><br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h2>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>


function addGreeting(){
  $temp = $("<h3></h3>");
  $temp.append('Hello user');
  $("#addviewtask:nth-child(2)").append($temp);
}
```

Comment: so where in this html is it actually supposed to be appended? and when  is the function supposed to be called? on page load?

Comment: Your selector's the problem. You're targeting an ID (which denotes a unique element) yet further specifying the second child. Always check your selectors in jQuery before suspecting any other problem.

Comment: `function addGreeting(){
  var $temp = $("<h3></h3>").text('Hello user');
  $('#addviewtask>*:nth-child(2)').append($temp);
}`

Answer (score 0):

> `$("#addviewtask:nth-child(2)").append($temp);`

You're selecting `#addviewtask` which is the second child of its parent. If you want its second child, you'll need `"#addviewtask>*:nth-child(2)"`.